# SQL - Showing time passed since specific record created (new column)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have create some code that allows me to show every record that I have in my data after a specific subsymptom

```
SELECT
ID,
Received,
Closed,
Subsymptom,
DATEDIFF(HOUR, received, COALESCE(closed, GETDATE())) AS 'HoursOpen'
FROM
   vw_UserView_OpenAndClosed A
WHERE closed > 
(SELECT  MAX(closed)
FROM    
    vw_UserView_OpenAndClosed SUB
WHERE   
    Subsymptom = 'INSTALL'
    AND received >= '2017-06-01'
    AND SUB.name = A.name)
```

The data looks like this

```
ID      received    closed      Subsymptom            HoursOpen
1306438 2017-06-20  2017-06-21  ISSUES                19
1305393 2017-06-18  2017-06-19  REQUEST               12    
1299203 2017-06-05  2017-06-05  REQUEST               0
1299415 2017-06-05  2017-06-06  SPECIFIC FAILURE      2
```

What I want to be able to do is create a new column that tells me how much time has passed since the original subsymptom named 'INSTALL' was raised.

ID may have gaps and I will have more than one 'Name'

I have tried a Select Max(closed) Join but I cant get it to work at all and I think I am on the totally wrong track and have some mind fuzz.

Example Data

```
ID      Received    Closed     Subsymptom       Name     
1306438 2017-06-20  2017-06-21 ISSUES           BROOM       
1299203 2017-06-05  2017-06-05 REQUEST          BROOM       
1305393 2017-06-18  2017-06-19 REQUEST          CHIVE       
1299415 2017-06-06  2017-06-06 SPECIFIC FAILURE BROOM       
1299222 2017-06-05  2017-06-05 ISSUES           BROOM       
1299112 2017-06-05  2017-06-05 CONTACTLESS      BROOM
1279168 2017-06-01  2017-06-03 INSTALL          BROOM
1287965 2017-06-10  2017-06-10 INSTALL          CHIVE
```

Results Desired

```
ID      Received    Closed     Subsymptom       Name     HoursOpen  Days Received since Install Closed
1306438 2017-06-20  2017-06-21 ISSUES           BROOM    19         17
1299203 2017-06-05  2017-06-05 REQUEST          BROOM    0          2
1305393 2017-06-18  2017-06-19 REQUEST          CHIVE    12         21
1299415 2017-06-06  2017-06-06 SPECIFIC FAILURE BROOM    2          3
1299222 2017-06-05  2017-06-05 ISSUES           BROOM    0          2
1299112 2017-06-05  2017-06-05 ISSUES           BROOM    0          2
```

Days received since install closed - calculates the amount of days from the INSTALL close date to the RECEIVED date.

(later this will be graphed to show that after an INSTALL new records were received on Day 0, 1, 2, 3 etc)

Comment: It is helpful to include some sample data (not the results of your query, but the data in vw_UserView_OpenAndClosed)

Comment: good advice, thank you. just checking your answer at the moment, looking promising :)

Comment: Great - let me know if you need any modifications!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  Thank you for clarifying with your comments and adding the requested sample data.  It was a breeze once I had that.  So, in the future, please make sure to add it when posting your question to ensure the fastest response!

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID bigint, Received DATETIME, Closed DATETIME, Subsymptom varchar(50), [Name] varchar(50))
DECLARE @Now DateTime = GETDATE()

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES
(1306438 , '2017-06-20', '2017-06-21', 'ISSUES', 'BROOM'),
(1299203 , '2017-06-05', '2017-06-05', 'REQUEST', 'BROOM'),
(1305393 , '2017-06-18', '2017-06-19', 'REQUEST', 'CHIVE'),
(1299415 , '2017-06-06', '2017-06-06', 'SPECIFIC FAILURE', 'BROOM'),
(1299222 , '2017-06-05', '2017-06-05', 'ISSUES', 'BROOM'),
(1299112, '2017-06-05', '2017-06-05', 'CONTACTLESS', 'BROOM'),
(1279168 , '2017-06-01', '2017-06-03', 'INSTALL', 'BROOM'),
(1287965 , '2017-06-10', '2017-06-10', 'INSTALL', 'CHIVE')

SELECT  T.ID, 
        T.Received, 
        T.Closed, 
        T.Subsymptom,
        T.[Name],
        DATEDIFF(HH, T.Received, COALESCE(T.Closed, @Now)) AS 'HoursOpen',
        DATEDIFF(DD, T2.Closed, T.Received) AS [Days Received since Install Closed]
FROM @Table T
JOIN @Table T2
    ON T.[Name] = T2.[Name]
    AND T2.Subsymptom = 'INSTALL'
WHERE T.Closed > T2.Closed
```

Here are the results:

```
(6 row(s) affected)
ID                   Received                Closed                  Subsymptom                                         Name                                               HoursOpen   Days Received since Install Closed
-------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------------
1306438              2017-06-20 00:00:00.000 2017-06-21 00:00:00.000 ISSUES                                             BROOM                                              24          17
1299203              2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 REQUEST                                            BROOM                                              0           2
1305393              2017-06-18 00:00:00.000 2017-06-19 00:00:00.000 REQUEST                                            CHIVE                                              24          8
1299415              2017-06-06 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06 00:00:00.000 SPECIFIC FAILURE                                   BROOM                                              0           3
1299222              2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 ISSUES                                             BROOM                                              0           2
1299112              2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 CONTACTLESS                                        BROOM                                              0           2

(6 row(s) affected)
```

What you're guaranteeing is that there will only be ONE instance of an 'INSTALL' Subsymptom for each Name.  If that is the case, this query will always work.  The reason my results are different than yours is because you only provided dates (not DateTimes), so the calculations will be slightly off.  But, basically, you're just joining each record to its original install - grabbing that original record's closed time - and comparing it to the received time of the current record.  Very simple - and straightforward.

Please let me know if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: The Join calculates the "received" from the date that the record was received rather than the date the install record was received. The Cross Apply returns no results at all, that said I think the Cross Apply is the more viable but needs a tweak. I will play around with it a bit and see what happens and get back to you

Comment: @Michael Understood.  If you could please provide some sample data (and your expected results), this will be very easy for me to update.  Or you can tweak it on your own.  I'm here for another 5 hours... :)

Comment: added sample data and expected results to the original post

Comment: @Michael Good job on including that info - check out the edited answer and let me know what you think.